# Which version of the iPhone SDK should I use for an OS4 app?

Tags: iphone

I'm wondering if I will have compatibility issues with OS4.0 if my app is built with the 4.1 SDK, or is this a non-issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is: Use a **Base SDK Version** of at least 4.0 for your application and a **Deployment Target Version** of exactly 4.0.

I've downvoted both answers because they are wrong or at least incomplete.

When building applications there are two settings that you should be aware of:

There is the **Base SDK Version** which defines against which version of the SDK your application will be compiled.

There is also the **Deployment Target Version** which defines the **lowest** version of the iOS that your application **requires**. You can set this to as low as 2.2.1 in Xcode but the App Store will not accept versions lower then 3.1.3 at the moment.

The *Base SDK Version* can be **higher** then the *Deployment Target Version*. This simply means that your application is backward compatible with older version of the iOS. This also means that your app needs to make decisions at runtime to be sure not to use newer functionality when running on an older version.

For example, the `MFMessageComposeViewController` was introduced in 4.0 so if your app has been configured to also run on 3.1.3 then you should use `NSClassFromString()` to find if that specific class is actually available before you use it.

There are many questions here on Stack Overflow on how to discover available functionality so I will not repeat those techniques here.

Comment: you are correct about the Deployment target version, I completely missed that

Answer (score 0):

And a somewhat important note:

Behaviour *does* change across OS releases. There were a pile of changes in 3.0 (we had issues with UITableView/UITableViewCell):

- Some changes happened on old apps (e.g. compiled for 2.2.1). I forget what these were.
- Some of them were in the *toolchain* (I think they changed how nibs were compiled with ibtool; it was something like setting both an image and a custom view for a UITableViewCell). This happened when we upgraded the SDK on the build server, even if we didn't touch "Base SDK"
- Some of them happen only when you compiled with a Base SDK of 3.0 (UIKit automagically detects which version you've linked against and has backwards-compatability  modes for some things)

Additionally, there were some runtime/C++ changes in GCC 4.2, which meant a GCC 4.2 app running on OS 2.2.1 crashed when casting unsigned int/long to float/double or using std::ostringstream. I've since added a check for GCC version.

So no, compiling with a newer SDK *can* result in issues — you might not want to risk it if there are time constraints (you don't have time to implement multitasking support, or you don't have time to do a complete re-test and fix all the bugs, or so). Or maybe you still want to support 2.2.1 for some strange reason (4.0 dropped 2.x "device support", which effectively made it impossible to debug apps on 2.x devices).

Usually nothing breaks across minor OS releases (discounting 3.1/3.2). I'd recommend upgrading SDKs as soon as you have the time; don't shy away from new features just because old OSes don't have them.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on the APIs you will be using. Let's say you want to implemented in-app texting (`MFMessageComposeViewController`) and want ALL of your end-users (will be defined as EUs) to access that feature then you'll have to compile against iOS 4.0. But let's say you want the in-app texting to be optional and a "plus" for your EUs, you'll just compile your app against iOS 3.0 (let's say).

Hope I answered your question :-)